# Segmentation Faults when testing typed actors with custom atoms

Tags: c++-actor-framework

I am trying to use the testing macros with my actors but I am getting a lot of segmentation faults.  I believe I have narrowed down the problem to my use of custom atoms.  To demonstrate the issue I modified the 'simple actor test' from [here](https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Testing.html) to make the adder strongly typed.

```
#include "caf/test/dsl.hpp"
#include "caf/test/unit_test_impl.hpp"
#include "caf/all.hpp"

namespace {

    struct fixture {
        caf::actor_system_config cfg;
        caf::actor_system sys;
        caf::scoped_actor self;

        fixture() : sys(cfg), self(sys) {
            // nop
        }
    };

    using calculator_type = caf::typed_actor<caf::result<int>(int, int)>;

    calculator_type::behavior_type adder() {
        return {
          [=](int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
          }
        };
    }

} // namespace

CAF_TEST_FIXTURE_SCOPE(actor_tests, fixture)

CAF_TEST(simple actor test) {
    // Our Actor-Under-Test.
    auto aut = self->spawn(adder);
    self->request(aut, caf::infinite, 3, 4).receive(
        [=](int r) {
            CAF_CHECK(r == 7);
        },
        [&](caf::error& err) {
            // Must not happen, stop test.
            CAF_FAIL(err);
        });
}

CAF_TEST_FIXTURE_SCOPE_END()
```

This works great.  I then took it one step further to add a custom atom called "add_numbers"

```
#include "caf/test/dsl.hpp"
#include "caf/test/unit_test_impl.hpp"
#include "caf/all.hpp"

CAF_BEGIN_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(calc_msgs, first_custom_type_id)
    CAF_ADD_ATOM(calc_msgs, add_numbers)
CAF_END_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(calc_msgs)

namespace {

    struct fixture {
        caf::actor_system_config cfg;
        caf::actor_system sys;
        caf::scoped_actor self;

        fixture() : sys(cfg), self(sys) {
            // nop
        }
    };

   using calculator_type = caf::typed_actor<caf::result<int>(add_numbers, int, int)>;

    calculator_type::behavior_type adder() {
        return {
          [=](add_numbers, int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
          }
        };
    }

} // namespace

CAF_TEST_FIXTURE_SCOPE(actor_tests, fixture)

CAF_TEST(simple actor test) {
    // Our Actor-Under-Test.
    auto aut = self->spawn(adder);
    self->request(aut, caf::infinite, add_numbers_v, 3, 4).receive(
        [=](int r) {
            CAF_CHECK(r == 7);
        },
        [&](caf::error& err) {
            // Must not happen, stop test.
            CAF_FAIL(err);
        });
}

CAF_TEST_FIXTURE_SCOPE_END()
```

This compiles fine but produces a segmentation fault at runtime.  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I am not passing `calc_msgs` to anything.  How do I do that?  Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID block adds the compile-time meta data. But you also need to initialize some run-time state via

```
init_global_meta_objects<caf::id_block::calc_msgs>();
```

Ideally, you initialize this state before calling *any* other CAF function. In particular before initializing the actor system. CAF itself uses custom `main` functions for its test suites to do that (cf. [core-test.cpp](https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/master/libcaf_core/test/core-test.cpp)). In your case, it would look somewhat like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  using namespace caf;
  init_global_meta_objects<id_block::calc_msgs>();
  core::init_global_meta_objects();
  return test::main(argc, argv);
}
```

This probably means that you would need to put the type ID block into a header file. This is nothing special about the unit tests, though. If you run a regular CAF application, you need to initialize the global meta objects as well. `CAF_MAIN` can do that for you as long as you pass it the type ID block(s) or you need to call the functions by hand. The CAF manual covers this in a bit more detail here: https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/0.18.5/ConfiguringActorApplications.html#configuring-actor-applications.

If this is your only test at the moment, you can define `CAF_TEST_NO_MAIN` before including `caf/test/unit_test_impl.hpp` and then add the custom `main` function. Once you have multiple test suites, it makes sense to move the `main` to its own file, though.